# What's the definition of direct object and transitive verb?

Tags: meaning

The definition of a direct object is being a recipient of a transitive verb, and the definition of a transitive verb is: characterized by having it containing a direct object.

Can someone define the two words in laymens terms?

Comment: What reseach have you done?

Comment: [Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)) [transitive verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb). If you oppose a transitive verb to an intransitive verb the difference should be obvious. Maybe if you can indicate a particular source of confusion we could help.

Comment: Excellent question!

Comment: At a basic level, this belongs on ELL. 'The boy kicked the ball.' S-Vₜᵣₐₙₛᵢₜᵢᵥₑ-DO. Usually introduced via semantics: the direct object 'receives the action' of the verb. / Then syntactical arguments are applied. 'The boy owned a ball' still S-Vₜᵣₐₙₛᵢₜᵢᵥₑ-DO, though there's a relationship rather than an action involved. Passivisable. / Then the buns are readied. 'The piano has a stool.' Some grammarians have argued that 'a stool' should not be classed as a DO. ...  'I envied him his looks.' Some say two DOs here.

Comment: So the terms seem inherently ill-defined, and the circularly defined working definitions, with simple examples, are best used at a simple level.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Who says?

Comment: "His looks" can only be Od, and "him", being the receiver of my envy, is then Oi.

Comment: Unfortunately, explaining language often runs into circularities like this. Just like a dictionary gives the meaning of words in terms of other words, and if you keep following those definitions you will often return back where you start. So it's hard to define them based on basic principles, except maybe for linguistics experts, and we generally resort to examples.

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean by "runs into circularities like this? Are you talking about programming languages?

Comment: Why was this superb linguistics question on EL&U migrated to ELL? I could understand it being migrated to Linguistics ...

Comment: @BillJ I just meant that you have to use language to explain language, provide definitions, etc. A dictionary doesn't work if you don't already know most of the language. You can easily run into chains of definitions like "circular: like a circle" and "circle: a shape that's circular".

Answer (score 0):

Direct object is the one who gets the effect of a verb diectly.In the sentence 'He hit the ball hard.' the ball gets the effect of the action hitting. The ball here is the direct object.
Transitive verb is that which must take at least one object to complete a sentence.

Comment: What about *her brother* in *She survived her brother* or *Bob* in *Bob received a blow to the chin*?